# Importing a third party binary to Artifactory from a Windows PC

Tags: artifactory

I would like to keep customized versions of third party binaries (.exe, .bin etc.) in artifactory, which eventually will be used together with Bamboo and Ansible to automate and repeat setup of those softwares.

But I cannot find a way to Upload the binary from my windows PC to the artifactory -- these bin files are not classic jar files per se with associated metadata, so I was hoping to find a way to create a custom repo(which I did create) and a way to upload the binary(which I am not able to).

Under "Import Repository from Path", I cannot browse my local file system from artifactory as it is showing a remote file system which I find a bit weird. So I manually pasted the path, which resulted in an error. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

```
2015-05-06 11:07:07,335 [art-exec-1] [INFO ] (o.a.r.d.i.DbRepoImportHandler:125) - third-party-bin import started /C:/Users/zencv/Downloads/alfresco-community-5.0.d-installer-linux-x64.bin
2015-05-06 11:07:07,336 [art-exec-1] [ERROR] (o.a.r.d.i.DbRepoImportHandler:127) - Error Import: Cannot import null, non existent folder or non directory file '/C:/Users/zencv/Downloads/alfresco-community-5.0.d-installer-linux-x64.bin'.
2015-05-06 11:07:07,337 [art-exec-795758] [ERROR] (o.a.r.s.ImportJob   :153) - Import had failed due to java.lang.NullPointerException: null
2015-05-06 11:07:07,337 [art-exec-795758] [ERROR] (o.a.r.s.ImportJob   :157) - Error occurred during import: null: NullPointerException
2015-05-06 11:07:07,338 [art-exec-795758] [INFO ] (o.a.r.s.ImportJob   :134) - Import of 1 repositories completed
2015-05-06 11:07:34,706 [art-exec-1] [INFO ] (o.a.r.d.i.DbRepoImportHandler:125) - third-party-bin import started /C:/Users/zencv/Downloads/alfresco-community-5.0.d-installer-linux-x64.bin
2015-05-06 11:07:34,706 [art-exec-1] [ERROR] (o.a.r.d.i.DbRepoImportHandler:127) - Error Import: Cannot import null, non existent folder or non directory file '/C:/Users/zencv/Downloads/alfresco-community-5.0.d-installer-linux-x64.bin'.
2015-05-06 11:07:34,707 [art-exec-795765] [ERROR] (o.a.r.s.ImportJob   :153) - Import had failed due to java.lang.NullPointerException: null
2015-05-06 11:07:34,707 [art-exec-795765] [ERROR] (o.a.r.s.ImportJob   :157) - Error occurred during import: null: NullPointerException
2015-05-06 11:07:34,708 [art-exec-795765] [INFO ] (o.a.r.s.ImportJob   :134) - Import of 1 repositories completed
```

Comment: have to ask - you are not running browser in virtual machine? I have no issues with browsing my directories ( artifactory 2.6.4 )

Comment: @freakman No, I am running natively on Windows, using Chrome browser (I dont think browser may have mattered anyway as the behaviour is coming from server side)

Answer (score 1):

You have an option to deploy files from the Artifactory UI.
To do so, simply click the "Deploy" tab, upload the desired file and deploy it to the target repository

[image]

For mote information see the [deploying artifacts](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Deploying+Artifacts) section in the Artifactory documentation.